# uploading multiple pictures causeing 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mod-security

I modified a script i found on here to do process multiple pictures being uploaded at once.  However when I try to run the script it throws an error. I use to have the script only allow one picture upload at time and that worked fine without any issue.

Here is my code.

```
Function uploadMultiple(){
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif',
        'upload_path' => $this->board_path,
        'overwrite' => false,
        //'file_name' => $fileName

    );
    //print_r($config);

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $errorCount = 0;
    $results = array(
        'errorsPresent' => false,
    );
    $successCount = 0;

    //for each image...try to upload.  if it fails, add it to the error list.
    //keep a list of successful uploads.
    print_r($_FILES);
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($_FILES); $i++){
        echo 'here';
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']    = $_FILES['userfile' . $i]['name'];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $_FILES['userfile' . $i]['type'];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile' . $i]['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $_FILES['userfile' . $i]['error'];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $_FILES['userfile' . $i]['size'];

        $config['file_name']     = 'img_' . time() . '.png'; //inserts the unix time into the file name.
        $config['upload_path']   = $this->board_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '0';
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
            $results['errorsPresent'] = true;
            $results['error'][$errorCount] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $errorCount ++;

        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());              
            $pictureData = $this->upload->data();
            $file_location = $pictureData['full_path'];
            $file_location = substr($file_location, 18);//this should probably be dynamic...
            $file_location = $this->db->escape($file_location);
            $results['success'][$successCount] = $file_location;

            chmod($pictureData['full_path'], 777); //don't need to give it execute permissions but oh well.
            $successCount ++;       
        }

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Here is the 500 error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server
>   Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request.

This is what the apache log file says:

> [Wed Mar 23 02:29:41 2011] [error] [client 129.21.129.32] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 500 (phase 4). Pattern match "(?:\b(?:(?:s(?:elect list because it is not contained in (?:an aggregate function and there is no|either an aggregate function or the) GROUP BY clause|upplied argument is not a valid (?:(?:M(?:S |y)|Postgre)SQL|O(?:racle|DBC)))|S(?:yntax error converti ..." at RESPONSE_BODY. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_50_outbound.conf"] [line "23"] [id "970003"] [msg "SQL Information Leakage"] [severity "WARNING"] [tag "LEAKAGE/ERRORS"] [hostname "hostname.com"] [uri "/longboard/index.php/board/add"] [unique_id "TYmTVYEVgWYAAASKoIcAAAAJ"]

Based on the error message I think modsecurity is blocking the script for some reason but i'm not sure why.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you please post the `$results` variable here?

Comment: The page errors with the 500 error and thus none of my echo or print_r statements print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a database error.  Mod_security was blocking the error message.  I went into the mod_security log file and found which rule was causing it to throw the 500 error.  I then went into the file with that rule and commented it out.  I restarted apache and retested and then the database error showed.  I'm thinking of leaving this rule commented out since this is a development server.  (It does broadcast to the whole world though, and the reason I have Mod_security installed.)

Answer (score 0):

try disabling mod_security ,
in .htaccess add this

```
SecFilterEngine Off
```